# Serial port communication error, "The requested resource is in use."

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

Here is the code which reads data from a serial port. To keep the things simple, let's do it on a button click;

```
    private System.IO.Ports.SerialPort serialPort;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort == null)
            serialPort = new SerialPort("COM7", 4800, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            //COM7 is hard coded just for the sake of example

        if (!serialPort.IsOpen)
            serialPort.Open();

        textBox1.AppendText(serialPort.ReadExisting());
    }
```

The code runs perfectly fine unless my laptop goes to sleep. When the system wakes-up from sleep, the `serialPort` object is not `null` but `serialPort.IsOpen` returns `false` and I get the error, **"The requested resource is in use."** while calling `serialPort.Open()`. There is nothing in the inner exception.[image]

I have tried many things with `serialPort` object like closing, disposing or explicitly assigning it to null and reinitialization but it's of no use, same error on same line every time.

```
        if (!serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            try
            {
                serialPort.Open();
            }
            catch
            {
                serialPort.Close();
                serialPort.Dispose();
                serialPort = null;

                serialPort = new SerialPort("COM7", 4800, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
                serialPort.Open();
            }
        }
```

I also have tried `serialPort.DataReceived` event but the event is not fired once the system woke-up from sleep.

The only workaround is to stop the application and run it again. I will really appreciate if anyone give me a clue to sort it out in a decent manner.

Comment: Well you could try to close connection when system is going to sleep and try to reopen on resume.

Comment: Do you use real serial port or some kind of port emulation? Try this program on real serial port.

Comment: @AlexFarber It's a real serial port, a GPS device is connected to it.

Comment: @Reniuz Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried it with SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged event and it works. Would be glad to accept your answer, if you please post.

Comment: Nice that this helped to you. Could you edit my answer and add the actual code that worked in your case?

Comment: @Reniuz I have posted the code, I guess you have to approve it.

Comment: Yes i had to. Thank you.

Comment: And don't forget to detach event! Posted caution section from documentation in answer.

Comment: @Reniuz yes i ll do this in the actual application. thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I suggested in comment the workaround could be made by using `SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged` event to detect when system is about to suspend. When that state is detected you need to close serial port and reopen it when operating system is about to resume from a suspended state.

hamad confirmed that this workaround works.

Here is the code.

```
SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged;

void SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Mode != PowerModes.Resume)
        serialPort.Close();
}
```

---

Also note from documentation of event:

**Caution**

**Because this is a static event, you must detach your event handlers when your application is disposed, or memory leaks will result.**